# How do retrieve imploded images and display in slides from database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to retrieve imploded images from the database in Laravel and display it in slides using foreach loop statement.

Stored Images in database column:

[image]

Controller:

```
$post= DB::table('posts')->paginate(4);
return view('welcome',compact('post'));
```

`view.blade` slides:

```
@foreach($post as $posts)

 <div class="carousel-inner rounded-lg">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{asset('admin/upload/images/$posts->image')}}" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{asset('admin/upload/images/$posts->image')}}" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{asset('admin/upload/images/$posts->image')}}" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{asset('admin/upload/images/$posts->image')}}" alt="Fourth slide">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: use php [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one more loop :

```
@foreach(explode("|", $posts->image) as $key => $value)
  <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ asset('admin/upload/images/' . $value) }}" alt="">
  </div>
@endforeach
```